# error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, adminlte

I made several graphic with Chart.js that works. But the polar graphic and the radar does not work. I get the following error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

I use charjs 2.3.0

I do not understand where the error can come .

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
     <canvas class="box box-warning" id="myChart4" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
     <canvas class="box box-warning" id="myChart5" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Chart Polar
//////////////////////////////////////////////

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart4");

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow"
        ],
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        cutoutPercentage: 50,
        animation: {
            animateScale: false
        }
    }
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Radar
//////////////////////////////////////////////

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart5");


var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: data = {

        labels: ["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche", ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'the first dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            data: [10, 34, 50, 34, 56, 65, 43]
        }, {
            label: 'the second dataset',

            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',

            data: [54, 72, 100, 36, 76, 23, 21]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: After trying the same version of Chart.js with your code, it works fine. No errors. Are you sure it's a Chart.js issue? https://jsfiddle.net/vwh2zsn9/

Comment: My code is good then the problem is elsewhere I made ​​a jsbin with my code : https://jsbin.com/wehalay/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is this line:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('sexe');
```

you do not have any element with id "sexe" on the page

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the element not being present in the HTML when Chart.js was trying to attach the chart on it.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Angular 2+, try to build the options and data chart in. I needed to do this because I used an @Input() attribute to get the data shown in the chart:

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
      this.options = {
       responsive: true,
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       ...
      }
    }
```

That's works for me. Hope it helps someone.